# How can I search based on file contents? (GUI, not terminal)

Tags: files, search, text

Every question and answer I've seen so far is ancient or just about `grep` in the terminal.

I want an easy way to search my `~/code` folder for certain strings. And I want the interface to allow filtering by file extension, etc.

I thought this would be built into Ubuntu. Is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Which icon are you talking about? I've tried  within the main Files app. Thanks, @user68186

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`catfish`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Catfish)? It is available from the App Center and looks like it can do what you want. I tried it but, being a command line addict, I personally love the level of power, flexibility and speed that `find` and `grep` can provide. Hope this is useful.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! https://docs.xfce.org/apps/catfish/usage#file_type_filters